# Open MailComposer in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, email, webview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a webView in my app which loads from local HTML file.
HTML file contains a Mail link.
if I click on mail then it opens **Default Mail Application** to send mail.
But I need to open a mailComposer within my app.

**my code is as follow**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"%@",request.URL);
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {  
        MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            NSString *strEmail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.URL];
            NSString *subString = [[strEmail componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] lastObject];
            [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:subString, nil]];
            [composer setSubject:@"Kreativ-Q"];
            [composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:YES];
            [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
            [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
        }    }
    return YES;
}
```

**help me to solve this**

**Thanks**

Comment: Here your mail Link is Only clickable not all web view Link?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper, I already check for that using condition in webview delegate method.